# ASP.NET MVC CORE. Получение конфигурации в контроллерах и сервисах

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Как получить объект `IConfigurationRoot` из класса `Startup` в любом контроллере или сервисе?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.6.php и https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.17.php

Comment: @AK к сожалению по вашем ссылкам нет информации о том, как получить объект IConfiguration в контроллере или методе. У меня есть варианты, вроде сделать статический класс, доступный из любого места приложения, но я думаю должен быть более правильным метод, используя например механизмы dependency injection или что-то вроде того.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход заключается в создании строго типизированного класса конфигурации со структурой, которая соответствует разделу в вашем файле конфигурации (или везде, где загружается ваша конфигурация):

```
public class MyConfig 
 {
   public string StringSetting { get; set; }
   public int IntSetting { get; set; }
}
```

Пишем все конфигурации в файл `appsettings.json`.Например

```
{
  "Logging":
 {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel":
    {
       "Default": "Debug",
       "System": "Information",
       "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
 },
   "MyConfig ":
  {
    "StringSetting": "My Value",
    "IntSetting": 23
  }
}
```

И чтобы  файл был привязан к классу конфигурации, вам нужно сделать 2 вещи.
1. Настройте `ConfigurationBuilder` для загрузки файла
2. Привяжите свой класс настроек к разделу конфигурации
Когда вы создаете новое приложение ASP.NET Core из шаблонов по умолчанию, ConfigurationBuilder уже настроен в Startup.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.AddUserSecrets();
}

builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Чтобы связать класс настроек с вашей конфигурацией, вам нужно настроить метод `ConfigureServices` в `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.Configure<MyConfig >(options => 
Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig ").Bind(options));
}
```

Когда вам нужно получить доступ к значениям `MyConfig` , вам просто нужно ввести экземпляр класса `IOptions<>` в потребительский контроллер.
Служба `IOptions<>` предоставляет свойство `Value`, которое содержит ваш настроенный класс `MyConfig` .

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private MySettings _settings;
   public HomeController(IOptions<MySettings> settings)
   {
      _settings = settings.Value;
   }
}
```

Для более подробного описания перейдите по [ссылке](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2)