# Файл конфигурации в .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Подскажите, как в .net core создавать и использовать файл кофигурации (то что в .net framework было .settings файлом, добавляемым в проект).
Читаю про Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, но не уверен что это то, что мне надо.

Comment: Есть пакет `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`. Может быть там реализован данный функционал. По крайней мере там как-то покрывается `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`. Может быть только заглушками, то есть работать будет только на винде, а на других ОС будет выкидываться `PlatformNotSupportedException`... Надо проверять, сам не пробовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конфигурация приложения в `ASP.NET Core` представляет объект интерфейса `IConfiguration`, либо интерфейса `IConfigurationRoot`, который наследуется от `IConfiguration`. Данный объект хранит все конфигурационные настройки в виде набора пар "ключ"-"значение".Основная функциональность по работе с конфигурацией сосредоточена в пакете `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. Это пакет также позволяет определить некоторые конфигурационные настройки в памяти.
Если возьмем проект `ASP.NET Core` по типу `Empty`, который изначально не содержит никакой конфигурации. В первую очередь добавим в проект через пакетный менеджер `Nuget` пакет `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.И изменим стандартный класс `Startup` следующим образом

```
namespace ConfigurationApp{ public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
        // строитель конфигурации
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"firstname", "Tom"},
                {"age", "31"}
            });
        // создаем конфигурацию
        AppConfiguration = builder.Build();

    }
    // свойство, которое будет хранить конфигурацию
    public IConfiguration AppConfiguration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    } 

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(AppConfiguration["firstname"]);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Для использование конфигурации можете обратиться к нужной настройке по ключу

```
string firstName = AppConfiguration["firstname"];
```

Для создания объекта `IConfigurationRoot` применяется метод `Build()` класса `ConfigurationBuilder`. А с помощью объекта `IConfigurationSource` для `ConfigurationBuilder` устанавливается источник конфигурационных настроек.Как правило, установка конфигурации производится в конструкторе класса `Startup`. Поэтому для определения конфигурации приложения в класс добавлен конструктор, а для хранения конфигурации определено свойство `AppConfiguration`. Все настройки конфигурации будут храниться в памяти. Для добавления настроек применяется метод `AddInMemoryCollection()`, который в качестве параметра принимает словарь. Каждый элемент такого словаря представляет отдельную конфигурационную настройку.
 Например, `{"firstname", "Tom"}` - ключ настройки `"firstname"`, а значение - `"Tom"`. Далее этот элемент попадает в конфигурацию приложения.
Для задания конфигурации используются различные источники - данные в памяти, файлы `JSON, XML, INI`. При этом мы можем использовать сразу несколько источников. Но надо учитывать, что при определении объекта `IConfiguration` мы должны указать как минимум один источник.
Для дополнительной информации воспользуйтесь этими ссылками
[Провайдеры конфигурации](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.16.php)

[Конфигурация в .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/mt632279.aspx)

[Получение конфигурации в контроллерах и сервисах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683950/194837)

**.NET Core console application**
**1.** Добовляем пакет `Nuget`
Базовый пакет `AI Nuget` является минимальным, чтобы работать `Application Insights` в консольном приложении `.NET Core`.Добовляем последную версию.

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

**2.** В следующем примере кода показано, как установить `instrumentation key` в экземпляре конфигурации по умолчанию `Application Insights`, а также создать и использовать `TelemetryClient` напрямую. По умолчанию `TelemetryConfiguration` - это синглтон, который будет работать до тех пор, пока приложение не завершится, и вы можете создать клиента телеметрии в любом месте, где хотите, без конструктора без аргументов, и он будет использовать экземпляр конфигурации по умолчанию.

```
 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = 
            "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555";
        TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
        client.TrackTrace("Demo application starting up.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            client.TrackEvent("Testing " + i);
        }

        client.TrackException(new Exception("Demo exception."));
        client.TrackTrace("Demo application exiting.");
        client.Flush();
    }
}
```

Пример является довольно упрощенным для установки ключа инструментария. Лучшей альтернативой могло бы быть чтение значения из конфигурации. Ниже приведен пример чтения из переменной среды.

```
        IConfiguration config =  new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                   .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
        string iKey = config["AI_KEY"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(iKey))
        {
            return -1;
        }
```

Установливаем переменную окружения `AI_KEY` по мере необходимости.
Или же можно прочитать из файла `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": 
   {
      "InstrumentationKey": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"
   }
}
```

Добовляем `json` файл в `IConfiguration`

```
 IConfiguration config =  new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();
        string ikey = config["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
```

[Logging and Configuration In A .NET Core Console Application](http://pioneercode.com/post/dependency-injection-logging-and-configuration-in-a-dot-net-core-console-app)

Comment: Но это ведь для ASP.NET. А если у меня обычное консольное приложение? В частности вызывает сомнения вот эта строчка: AppConfiguration = builder.Build();

Comment: наверное вам сразу к вопросу надо было прикрипеть в какой проекте вы работаете

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Один из достаточно простых решений -- это сериализация данных. Для начала надо описать класс конфигурации приложения, который должен содержать открытые поля:

```
[Serializable]
public class Config
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public float SomeFloat { get; set; }
}
```

Так же надо добавить методы сериализации и десериализации. Я предпочитаю XML и соответственно класс **XmlSerializer**, но можно использовать и **BinaryFormatter** или **JsonSerializer** либо другие классы с данными функционалом.

```
public void Write(TextWriter writer)
{
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
    x.Serialize(writer, this);
}
public static Config Read(TextReader reader)
{
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
    return (Config)x.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Далее вы можете читать конфигурации из файлов либо других источников данных, а так же сохранять измененные данные.

Полный пример написал на [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ySd2qb).

Сериализация представляет собой достаточно мощный инструмент, способный работать не только с одним классом, как в моем примере. Более подробно можете ознакомится по ссылке: [Примеры сериализации XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)